# How can I flag an editor's defaming edit message?

Tags: support, flags, suggested-edits, editor, code-of-conduct

I came across this suggested edit linked below. **The edit itself is ok*. However, the edit message itself is defaming**.
Rejecting an edit could be bad for the post, and furthermore a reject would only be a small noise and not an actual flag.
Disregarding the quality of the edit, I am wondering is there another option **how I could raise a flag on the editor?**

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/35444258

*I am wondering about a more general case. Here one could still say it's not improving.

Comment: Reject and edit might be an option but a flag of some kind would seem to be warranted.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/229325/how-to-deal-with-inappropriate-comments-attached-to-edits

Comment: Thanks for the links. Im still wondering about the "How" to actually flag/bring to attention?

Comment: Find one of their questions or answers and raise a moderator flag and link to the relevant edit?

Comment: Doesn't have to be one of their @Paulie_D . It could be the post they did the suggested edit on. The key is putting good context (links) in the custom flag.

Comment: "defaming" ? Yeah, that comment was inappropriate, but hardly anyone would have seen it. Meanwhile you pretty much publicly shamed the person who wrote it by posting about it on meta and linking to the edit. Now, who's doing the defaming?

Answer (score -3):

Summary from the comments:

Use the  "In need of moderator intervention" flag and point to the edit in question.

Comment: Why not just accept the proposed duplicate candidate, if that answers the question.

Comment: I did not think that it covered the how part. While "If you see a pattern of rudeness anywhere (including edit summaries), flag it. " Is useful, it did not answer my question *how to do it/Where to raise the flag?* which I was still wondering about afterwards.

Comment: If you think answers at the duplicate are lacking detail, the best thing is to provide an answer *there* and expand on the part that needs detail.